# Можете пояснить что это такое и как это вылечить?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-support-library

Никак не хочет создавать apk-файл, и появляется такая ошибка в Android Studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Comment: Написано же что надо сделать :)

Comment: Вам же все подробно описали в логе

Comment: А можно это перевести на на язык  для тугодумов ?

Comment: По всей видимости у вас не совпадают версии support-библиотек.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Версии support-библиотек различаются:

```
com.android.support:design:25.3.0
com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
```

Их нужно выровнять, например, так:

```
com.android.support:design:25.3.1
com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
```

Поправьте в зависимостях в вашем проекте.